# Best option to graph data in list with SharePoint Online

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, image-display

I'm looking for an option to display data from a list I have in SharePoint online (hosted as part of office 365) but my options seem very limited

does anyone know a for sure option. I do not mind paying for the product.

Thanks

Comment: Display it how? In charts or graphs?

Comment: Pie charts,Bar charts, Line charts.. I don't think well need anything too advanced to start off with but basicly what is avaiable in excel at somepoint someone will ask for it

Comment: Hi Crash893! Colbs posted the working answer.

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js is a free library and it pretty awesome to work with. Here is a quick little sample I used to create a pie graph / KPI. All you have to do is set the 'salesPercent'

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

```
<script src="Chart.js"></script>

<div id="foo">
   <canvas height='160' width='160' id='salesCanvas' ></canvas>
</div> 

<script>
var doughChart, ctx, data;
var salesPercent = $('#SalesPercent').text().replace("%", "");
//***Sales***
ctx = document.getElementById('salesCanvas').getContext('2d');
data = [
    {
        value: 100 - parseInt(salesPercent),
        color: "#EF7D31",
        highlight: "#EF7D31",
        label: "Goal"
    },
    {
        value: parseInt(salesPercent),
        color: "#005D84",
        highlight: "#005D84",
        label: "Actual"

    }
]

//Create new Doughnut chart for Sales
doughChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {
    animateScale: true,
    animateRotate: true
});

</script>
```

Comment: How would one pull data from a list with this?

Comment: depends on the context of the list and the type of code you want to use. I think that warrants another question

Comment: It really shouldnt be that hard to say point at list sales and graph a pie chart of district by sales $. or even a xy plot  why is this not just built into sharepoitn its built into excel online

Comment: You're right! Maybe a better option for you is Excel Services, although I haven't used it in the Online version

Comment: As far as I understand - for new version this code is not actual, but this library works. Colbs, Thank You Much!